# How to store remote directory listing to a file with Filezilla

Tags: ftp, dir, filezilla

Command line `ftp` no longer works for a remote site, so I'm now using FileZilla.  Fine for uploading and downloading, but how do I get a directory listing on the remote machine?

In `ftp`, I would type `dir  [remote directory name] [local file]`

I can't anywhere in FileZilla to download the remote directory to a file. What can I do ?

Comment: You should better move this question to [su] (flag it for moderator attention). It's off-topic here.

Answer (score 0):

FileZilla does not support any kind of automation.

You need to use some command-line FTP client. You did not specify what problem are you facing with command-line ftp now. So it's difficult to suggest you some solution. Nor you have specified what platform you are on.

Comment: That's disappointing FileZilla doesn't allow this. It would then be more productive to find out why ftp no longer works on my work.  I'm using a PC with Window 7, although I'm still a Unix user at heart from years ago. I've been using ftp all the time to download weather data from a NOAA server (ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov). I can still log on, but there is no response to any ftp commands that I enter, e.g., dir, cd, get, etc.

Comment: I looked at the Super User site, and found out how to change the Windows Firewall setting on ftp, so now it's working again.  Thanks for pointing me to this great resource !